# different aggregation functions for different columns

Tags: r, summary

I have a dataframe, that has the following columns:
  ID
  Factor 1 ->5  (5 columns; 1 per factor)
  Weeks of year (52 columns, 1 per week)

The weeks of the year contains volumes items, either 0, 1, 2, or in some cases upto 64.

The factors columns is a value that is a time for human interaction with an item.

Here's how the data looks:

[image: mydata]

As you can see in the attached file the ID can have multiple rows.

I want to do the following in r...I'd like to sum the volumes cells for all unique values of ID, and get the max for each factor by each unique value of ID.

I don't have any code to show as I'm not too familiar on how to do this in r.

What is my expected outcome: 
If I consider the ID ending in 250557, there are two instances.  I would expect Facotr 1 = 4; Factor 2 = 1, Factors 3,4,and 5 = 0.  Then looking horizontally per week,  I would expect the following...1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1

any help would be appreciated.  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: thinking out loud here after I post this....would it be better to subset the the table into the factor table and volume table, do the summing or maxing, then put them back again using the join left function in r??

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting factors to numeric for aggregation needs. Then run separate aggregations by column ranges and statistic (i.e., `max` and `sum`) and merge outputs together.

```
df[sapply(df, is.factor)] <- as.numeric(df[sapply(df, is.factor)])

factor_max_df <- aggregate(cbind(Factor1, Factor2, Factor3, Factor4, Factor5) ~ ID1, df, 
                           max)

volume_sum_df <- aggregate(. ~ ID1, subset(df, select=[-c(Factor1, Factor2, Factor3,
                                                          Factor4, Factor5)], 
                           sum)

final_df <- merge(factor_max_df, volume_sum_df, by="ID1")
```